# Want to use Nestjs with other Redis command

Tags: node.js, redis, nestjs, backend

I try to implement nestjs backend and redis as caching. I can do it according to the official document https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#in-memory-cache.

I use the package [`cache-manager-redis-store`](https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store) and the code in `app.module.ts` is as shown below.

```
import { Module, CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import * as Joi from 'joi';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          validationSchema: Joi.object({
            REDIS_HOST: Joi.string().default('localhost'),
            REDIS_PORT: Joi.number().default(6379),
            REDIS_PASSWORD: Joi.string(),
          }),
        }),
      ],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        store: redisStore,
        auth_pass: configService.get('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
        ttl: 0,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

With this setting, I can use `get` and `set` as expected but I want to use other redis command such as `hget` and `zadd`. Unfortunately, I cannot find the guide anywhere.

I think there must be a way since `cache-manager-redis-store` package said that it just passing the configuration to the underlying `node_redis` package. And [`node-redis`](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) package can use those fancy redis commands.

Would be appreciated if you have solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you both Micael Levi and Hamidreza Vakilian for the help. I did more research and found my solution so I will share it for other people have the same problem.

It seem `cache-manager-redis-store` allow only normal redis operation and if you want to use more, you have to access `cacheManager.store.getClient()` as Micael suggest.

`Cache` interface got no `getClient` but `RedisCache` had! The problem is `RedisCache` interface inside `cache-manager-redis-store` package don't export those interface for outsider.

The easiest way to fix this is to create `redis.interface.ts` or whatever name for your own.

```
import { Cache, Store } from 'cache-manager';
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';

export interface RedisCache extends Cache {
  store: RedisStore;
}

export interface RedisStore extends Store {
  name: 'redis';
  getClient: () => RedisClient;
  isCacheableValue: (value: any) => boolean;
}
```

Now you can replace `Cache` with `RedisCache` interface.

The usage will be as follows.

```
import {
  CACHE_MANAGER,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';
import { RedisCache } from './interface/redis.interface';

@Injectable()
export class RedisService {
  private redisClient: RedisClient;
  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: RedisCache) {
    this.redisClient = this.cacheManager.store.getClient();
  }

  hgetall() {
    this.redisClient.hgetall('mykey', (err, reply) => {
      console.log(reply);
    })
  }
}
```

Note that these `redisClient` commands do not return value so you have to use callback to get the value.

As you can see that the answer is in callback structure, I prefer `await` and `async` more so I did a little more work.

```
import {
  BadRequestException,
  CACHE_MANAGER,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';
import { RedisCache } from './interface/redis.interface';

@Injectable()
export class RedisService {
  private redisClient: RedisClient;
  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: RedisCache) {
    this.redisClient = this.cacheManager.store.getClient();
  }

  async hgetall(key: string): Promise<{ [key: string]: string }> {
    return new Promise<{ [key: string]: string }>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.redisClient.hgetall(key, (err, reply) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          throw new BadRequestException();
        }
        resolve(reply);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

By using promise, I can get the answer as if the function return. The usage is as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly redisService: RedisService) {}

  async getUserInfo(): Promise<{ [key: string]: string }> {
    const userInfo = await this.redisService.hgetall('mykey');
    return userInfo;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder what is the Redis version that you use, when I tried to use your solution (which looks amazing), I could not import this class `import { RedisClient } from 'redis';
`

Comment: @AbdallahSabri I use `redis:6.2-alpine`. I just clone my repo and test it again and it works just fine. So maybe your problem come from the version. Anyway here is my [package.json](https://pastebin.com/4ahYUqkS). If you still has problem, I can share my repo. Just email me.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the underlying redis client by calling
`cacheManager.store.getClient()` even tho the interface `Cache` (from `cache-manager`) doesn't has that `getClient` method defined. I don't know what's the best way to type that.

The return of that will be the Redis client created by `cache-manager-redis-store`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [nestjs-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-redis) package. It's compatible with typescript and is dependent on [ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) package thus you get all other Redis APIs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found another easy way!
You can import `RedisCache` from `cache-manager-redis-yet`, which is an official package and suggested by [node-cache-manager](https://github.com/node-cache-manager/node-cache-manager#store-engines).

this is the code sample:

```js
import { CACHE_MANAGER, Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisCache } from 'cache-manager-redis-yet';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cacheManager: RedisCache) {}

  get redis() {
    return this.cacheManager.store.client;
  }

  async getUserInfo(): Promise<{ [key: string]: string }> {
    const userInfo = await this.redis.hGetAll('mykey');
    return userInfo;
  }
}
```